# OpenMPI node & network topology

Tags: c, networking, mpi, openmpi, topology

i am currently building a small utility library as part of a larger project.
OpenMPI has a well documented API library but i am a little puzzled when it comes to the lower level communication between nodes.
I know that when writing your algorithm, you distribute it across all nodes that are expected to do the computation each communicating with the rest, executing portion of the algorithm based on their "global" MPI rank (as defined in the algorithm), and all the nodes synchronize back and forth. However, the reason i placed global in quotes is, does openMPI communicate on the ip level, hence say that i already have a long executing algorithm, but there is a node that is idling, not running any MPI processes, if i execute my MPI algorithm on it, will it join the MPI_COMM_WORLD and become part of the overall network topology or is there some "voodoo" i need to do to make that node part of the MPI_COMM_WORLD.
also, if nodes can become part of MPI_COMM_WORLD for that particular algorithm, how can i register/identify this new node?

any reading references are also helpful.

many thanks!

tl;dr are MPI nodes hot-swappable from the MPI_COMM_WORLD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot join nodes to a communicator once it has been created. This is also true for `MPI_COMM_WORLD` which is just a precreated communicator. Only the processes that are launched as part of the initial SPMD launch become part of `MPI_COMM_WORLD`. But you can spawn additional processes using the MPI-2 process management facilities, described in [Chapter 10](http://www.mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi22-report/node201.htm) of the current MPI Standard version 2.2.

The newly spawned processes have their own `MPI_COMM_WORLD` and the processes of the initial group can only communicate with them through a special **intercommunicator** (`MPI_COMM_WORLD` is **intracommunicator**) that is returned by the spawn operation. Since process spawning is a collective operation, all processes in `MPI_COMM_WORLD` will get a handle to that intercommuniator.

MPI 3.0 (when it's out sooner or later) will bring fall-through fault tolerance that will allow to exclude/remove faulty processes from `MPI_COMM_WORLD` (or from any other communicator) and MPI 3.1 will eventually bring something that will allow faulty processes to be replaced.

Comment: thnx for the quick reply; i am from bulgaria too btw, my name is Georgi :)

Comment: i have another quick question regarding the communication scheme; if i create a group communicator of selected nodes from MPI_COMM_WORLD in a particular process, is that process the only one that possesses that MPI_Group handle or is it created across all nodes that are part of this group?

Comment: Keep in mind that forward-looking statements about MPI-3 are not a sure thing.  The fault tolerance portions, for example, are *highly* controversial right now, and are not guaranteed to be part of MPI-3.

Comment: Per your comment question, MPI doesn't know anything about nodes -- it only understands *processes*. There is also no such thing as a "group communicator" -- communicators *have* a group, but they aren't quite the same thing. A group is a set of processes. A communicator is a group with a unique communication context. Example: you can send and receive on a communicator; you cannot send and receive on a group. So *if* I understand your question, MPI_Group handles are local, but some of the constructors are collective in nature (meaning that all processes have to invoke them).